# Statistics Query Water Quality MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I have a water quality database that I want to run some queries on. The table for this query has the following 4 columns:

Site_ID, SampleDate, Parameter, and Results

The data looks something like this (example)

LB-100, 1/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.2"

LB-100, 8/30/2015,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.2"

LB-100, 2/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.1"

LB-500, 1/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","8.0"

LB-100, 3/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.4"

LB-100, 4/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.4"

LB-100, 5/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.1"

I want to have a query that provides min, max, avg, SD, and count for all of 2014 at each selected Sample Site in order to create some annual reports. For the 7 example rows above, I would like to end up with one query output row that looks like this:

LB-100,"Calcium, Dissolved", 2.1, 2.4, 2.24, 0.14, 5 (these values correspond to min, max, avg, SD, and count for all 2014 data at LB-100).

So far, I have done the following in query design view. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8mgq.jpg)

The problem, the query returns the correct records but doesn't calculate the desired statistics. Instead, it simply returns 5 rows that look like this:

LB-100, 1/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.2", "2.2", "2.2", , 1

LB-100, 2/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.1", "2.1", "2.1", , 1

LB-100, 3/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.4", "2.4", "2.4", , 1

LB-100, 4/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.4", "2.4", "2.4", , 1

LB-100, 5/14/2014,"Calcium, Dissolved","2.1", "2.1", "2.1", , 1

Of course I could simply add a totals row in the results view to obtain the desired information, but this is not feasible since I have hundreds of stations and 50 or more parameters.

There has got to be an easy way to do this in a query?!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Learn SQL and GROUP BY.

Comment: you would want to `group by` `YEAR` , not `DATE`.Check the syntax to `EXTRACT YEAR` from `DATE` .

Comment: Did you try removing the check mark for column `SampleDate` in the "Show" row of your "Query by Example"?

Comment: Thanks for the input! Parfait provided the perfect answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your data returns exactly like the table rows is because your group level is equal to unit level. Basically, there are no groups to *group by* since your query is one-to-one with actual tables (notice your counts are all 1, aggregates are equal to each other, and standard deviation is empty).

Try removing the `SampleDate` field in aggregate query (as table seems to hold date level entries). By doing so, you can have groups by `Site ID` and `Parameter`. But do note, you can still filter by sample date in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT [SITE ID], [Parameter],
       Min(Results) As MinOfResults,
       Max(Results) As MaxOfResults,
       Avg(Results) As AvgOfResults,
       StDev(Results) As StDevOfResults,           
       Count(Results) As CountOfResults
FROM Chemistry1
WHERE [SITE ID] = 'LB-100' 
  AND [Parameter] = 'Calcium, Dissolved'
  AND Year([SampleDate]) = 2014
GROUP BY [SITE ID], [Parameter]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for also explaining the thought process behind it. Really helpful...now I should be able to apply the same concept to some other queries I have been struggling with!